# Hazelcast ignores logging type

Tags: hazelcast

My team has recently switched my application's backend logger. So, I added the following lines to my `hazelcast.yml`

```yaml
hazelcast:
  properties:
    hazelcast.logging.type: slf4j
```

Unfortunately, it insists on still attempting to use the Log4j config and gives me the following

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.28]
    at com.hazelcast.logging.Log4jFactory.createLogger(Log4jFactory.java:30) ~[hazelcast-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
etc
```

So, it's ignoring my change to the file. Now, if I set a system property

```
 -Dhazelcast.logging.type=slf4j
```

it works fine. Now, I don't want to do this as a system property if I can avoid it. It's just one more thing to remember to configure during deployment. But I simply don't know why the property value is being ignored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast uses Java Util Logging by default, so the exception you are getting means that somewhere you configured log4j.

Comment: Also, the `hazelcast.yml` file is read as part of start-up. Any part of Hazelcast logging before the config file is read won't be aware of your specification yet.